# Обновление виджетов PyQT

Tags: python, qt, combobox, pyqt

Здравствуйте. Есть программа, написанная на Python 3, с использование QT 5. Есть Несколько комбобоксов, при изменении которых изменяется другая часть окна.

Первый комбобокс выводит выбранную пользователем дату, к примеру:

**Combobox_1**

- вчера
- сегодня
- завтра

Второй отсчитывает от результатов первого несколько дней и выводит во вторую строку:

**Combobox_2**

- результаты combobox_1 + 1 день
- результаты combobox_1 + 2 день
- результаты combobox_1 + 3 день

Всё работает, НО! Если я поставил, к примеру 08.11.16, затем выбрал +1 день, то есть второй лейбл будет 09.11.16, а затем первый комбобокс изменил на 07.11.16, второй combobox не изменяется, всё так же остается 09.11.16. Как сделать, чтобы combobox'ы обновлялись?

Answer (score 1):

на combo1 поставить currentIndexChanged, который изменит combo2.setCurrentIndex

```
def set_combo2():
    text = self.combo1.currentText()
    index = date_list.index(text)
    self.combo2.setCurrentIndex(index)

self.combo1.currentIndexChanged.connect(set_combo2)
```